# Unable to use grok in Logstash pipeline to manipulate message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to use grok in our Logstash pipelines.
I would rather not share my entire file, but I am confident that the rest of the file is correct as we use it in our other pipelines.

What I have in my Logstash pipeline:

```
    {
       patterns_dir => "..\config\pattern"
       match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_PROMATIC:promatic_timestamp}%{SPACE}\[%{LOGLEVEL_SERILOG:log.level}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
    }
    date 
    {
        match => ["promatic_timestamp", "HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        remove_field => [ "promatic_timestamp" ]
    }
```

How the logging looks like:

```
15:05:05.303 [DBG] some random text file
```

What it now looks like:
[image]

What it should look like:
[image: ![enter image description here]

In other words, time stamp can be removed and the log level be assigned to the variable: log.level

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config solved my problem:

```
grok 
{
    patterns_dir => "..\config\pattern"
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_PROMATIC:promatic_timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL_SERILOG:log.level}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
date 
{
    match => ["promatic_timestamp", "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    remove_field => [ "promatic_timestamp" ]
}
```